# Generating a new independent variable from other independent variables in the dataset

Tags: machine-learning, interaction, dataset

I have a database of characteristics of a signal. The characteristics are a bunch of indicators (kurtosis,skewness,etc). The dependent variable is fault. The fault variable has as a value 1 if the signal corresponds to a faulty machine and 0 if it's not a faulty machine.

I would like to know if there is a method or an algorithm capable of generating indicators (new independent variable) from the ones in the database(e.g :the multiplication of 2 of them or division ) that would correlate better with the dependent variable and would consequently a better indicator of the existence of the fault.

Thank you !

NB : If technical terms are not well used or more details are needed, don't hesitate to ask me as I am new to the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at [variable interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)#In_regression). When building your model, consider something more of the form $y = (x_1 + x_2 + \dots +x_n)^2$, which will give you the pairwise interaction terms (higher exponents will reveal interactions between more variables). You can then see if these have low p-values, etc.

Also, since you say you're not up on the technical lingo, what you're trying to build is a binary classification model. You'll want to look into a linear regression linked to a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification).